# What might cause contribution amounts to multiply by 100 instead of recording values with a decimal place

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, currency

I'm working on a site where whenever a contribution is entered into civi with a decimal, it's multipled by 100. It's a lot like [this old issue](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-4038), except the site has not to my knowledge ever been localized and has always used USD.

In the localization settings if I change the decimal value to a comma and the thousands separator to a period and enter a contribution of $5,00 the contribution amount is 5. When I swap it back to the U.S. dollar defaults, entering 5.00 is a contribution amount of 500.  I can't replicate on any other site, but I can replicate when loading the civicrm database into a clean codebase and clean wordpress site. I've tested replacing the civicrm_setting table as this seemed like it may have been the culprit but that didn't help. Any clues to where else I could look for something problematic in the database?

Site is on 5.10.3 currently, it's an older install and no one remembers when this problem started.

Comment: Are you able to inspect the submitted values (using your browser's developer tools, eg [Firefox Network Tab > Request Params](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor/request_details) and see whether the submitted amount value is 5.00 or 500? That would help tell if the issue is clientside (before / during submission) or serverside (during processing).

Comment: CiviCRM has some issues with amounts being multiplied because the decimal sign wasn't applied correctly. In the Netherlands we use the comma (,) as a decimal separator. This bug was fixed and introduced a regression bug which had to do with adding extra zero's. That regression bug is fixed 5.11.0 See https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/407#note_14584

Comment: @chris-burgess -- thanks for the tip. In the request params, the value is 1.23, which is the same as what I enter. It then gets stored in the database as 123.00

Comment: I've updated my test site to 5.12 and still seeing the same behavior. Suppose I'll test 5.11 in case it was somehow re-introduced as a regression? But since this site is not localized to use any currency other than USD, and I can't replicate it on a demo or other site with the same configuration, I'm more and more convinced there's something odd in the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to solve this.

I looked at what adding a contribution touches in the database. I ruled out differences in the settings table, but then when I looked at `civicrm_currency` I found that in this database, some characters were not present, even though the encoding would support them. so for instance the `civicrm_currency` record `(6,'INR','₨','356','Indian Rupee')` in another database was `(6,'INR','','356','Indian Rupee')` in this one.

It's not quite clicking with me *why* the U.S. dollar amounts were being translated -- that record was not different at all. But swapping out the currency table with one from a different site resolved my issue.